# How do I eliminate duplicate logging in log4net?

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

I have a program that makes many log4net calls to the "myprogram" loggers. It also calls other code that makes log4net calls to other loggers. I want to capture all logs higher than INFO for "myprogram" and all logs higher than WARN for everything else. This way, I get the work-in-progress messages specific to the task I'm working on, but am still notified of potentially bad things happening in the supporting code. I want this sent to both Console and a log file.

I have the following log4net config:

```xml
<log4net>
    <root>
        <level value="WARN" />
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        <appender-ref ref="LogFile" />
    </root>
    <logger name="myprogram">
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        <appender-ref ref="LogFile" />
    </logger>
    <appender name="Console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%message%newline" />
        </layout>
        <threshold value="INFO" />
    </appender>
    <appender name="LogFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="- %utcdate %level %logger %ndc %thread %message%newline" />
        </layout>
        <appendToFile value="false" />
        <staticLogFileName value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Once" />
        <file value="mylogfile" />
        <immediateFlush value="true" />
        <threshold value="INFO" />
        <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
    </appender>
</log4net>
```

This makes perfect sense to me: log >WARN for everything and >INFO for the specific "myprogram" logger.

The problem is that I'm getting INFO messages logged **twice** on both Console and LogFile. This only happens if I have both the `<root>` and `<logger>` elements filled though; if I remove either one, then the remaining one works as I expect.

I could understand if I was getting double-logging of WARN entries (since myprogram matches both "root" and "myprogram"), but it's happening at INFO even though ROOT is (presumably) set to WARN.

Am I doing something wrong here, or is this a log4net bug/ambiguity?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You are getting duplicated because you are telling it to log messages twice. I wouldn't recommend using additivity here since you might experience some side effects, simply remove unnecessary configuration:

```xml
<root>
    <level value="WARN" />
    <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    <appender-ref ref="LogFile" />
</root>
<logger name="myprogram">
    <level value="INFO" />
</logger>
```

You don't need to indicate the appender-ref in the logger myprogram since it will inherit them from the root logger; if you specify them again it will log twice.

Comment: This worked well for me when I encountered the same problem.  This avoids the additivity issue as well

Comment: @Jeffrey are you aware of what the issues with using additivity are?  I have not been successful in finding anything documented that Google knows about.

Comment: @Tinister the additivity issue is having to set additivity=false (as in the question above) otherwise your output will be duplicated.

Comment: @Jeffrey Yes but from I can tell, using "additivity=false" is also an acceptable solution to the OP's problem.  Jam, in his or her answer, mentions that using additivty can produce "side-effects"; however, Jam's account seems to be deleted or something so I assume he will not available to respond.  Your first comment seems to indicate you're also aware of these "side-effect" issues so I thought I'd ask.

Comment: programmatically you can do this as follows: ((log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger)log.Logger).Additivity = false;

Answer (score 72):

Try with this change, setting additivity to false.

```xml
<root>
    <level value="WARN" />
    <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    <appender-ref ref="LogFile" />
</root>
<logger name="myprogram" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    <appender-ref ref="LogFile" />
</logger>
```

Comment: This is a good way to ensure all messages logged against the 'myprogram' log does not bubble up to the root logger.

Comment: Works for me; I want all log entries from a particular class to go to a different appender than the other classes.

Comment: @jaminator: That's a difficult question to answer in the space of a comment, and I'm not entirely sure what you're asking.  Are you asking why you might configure something like that?