# getting duplicate Log4Net entries

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

I am getting duplicate lines in my log output with the following web.config entries:

```
<root>
      <priority value="Off"/>
      <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>
   </root>
   <logger name="SessionMgr">
      <priority value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
    </logger>
```

If I take the  element out I get nothing, as I expect.  But, adding the  element results in ever line duplicated.

What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would try this instead:

```
   <root>
      <priority value="Off"/>
      <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>
   </root>
   <logger name="SessionMgr">
      <priority value="ALL" />
   </logger>
```

Your root logger already tells you to log to FileAppender.  You shouldn't need to add it in your SessionMgr logger.  You can also see this article for more details:

[Eliminate duplicate logging in log4net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651277/eliminate-duplicate-logging-in-log4net)

Comment: 6 years later for the win! Thank you.

Comment: 8 years later for the win! Thank you.

Comment: 10 years later for the win! Thank you.