# How to prevent duplicating event log message by setting app.config in log4net?

Tags: c#, log4net

I set the app.config for log4net as below in order to log some message every changed status.

I input additivity="false" after googling, but the duplicated message is still logged.

Would you please advice me to correct the below config so that duplicated message can be disapprearing?

```
<appender name="APP_TRACE_ONCE_LOG_EVENTREF" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" additivity="false">
  <File value="C:\Edwards\HMI\Test\TraceOnce\"/>
  <AppendToFile value="true"/>
  <MaxSizeRollBackups value="100"/>
  <DatePattern value="TraceOnce_dd.MM.yyyy.'log'"/>
  <MaximumFileSize value="512KB"/>
  <RollingStyle value="Composite"/>
  <StaticLogFileName value="false"/>
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <ConversionPattern value="[%-5p][%d]-[%m]%n"/>
  </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="APP_TRACE_ONCE_LOG_CONFIG">
  <level value="ALL"/>
  <appender-ref ref="APP_TRACE_ONCE_LOG_EVENTREF"/>
</logger>
```

Comment: * if the below steps are executed like
     HmiLog.Debug("Message A...");
     HmiLog.Debug("Message A...");
     HmiLog.Debug("Message A...");
     HmiLog.Debug("Message B...");
     HmiLog.Debug("Message B...");
     HmiLog.Debug("Message C...");
     HmiLog.Debug("Message C...");
     HmiLog.Debug("Message A...");
the message should be logged like
     Message A...
     Message B...
     Message C...
     Message A...
in text file after removing duplicated messages.

Comment: You have added additivity to the appender, but it should be on the logger, see the example on Eddie's answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651277/eliminate-duplicate-logging-in-log4net#661903